# The isolated points of a set $S$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is countable

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, solution-verification

I wanted to verify if my proof using Lindelöf covering theorem is correct.

Suppose $x \in S$ is an isolated point of $S$. This means that there exists $r_x$ such that $B(x,r_x) \cap S = \{x\}$.

Now consider the open covering of the isolated points $\{B(x,r_x)\}$. By the Lindelöf covering theorem, there is a countable subcollection of $\{B(x,r_x)\}$ that covers the isolated points. But this subcollection contains every single $B(x, r_x)$, otherwise it would not cover the missing point. So we have a bijection between the isolated points and the countable collection of n-balls, so the isolated points form a countable set.

Comment: This proof looks sound to me.